# Symfony 3 | Event во время изменений переменной в сущности

Tags: события, symfony, symfony3, doctrine2

В сущности Встреча(Meeting) есть надобнось, что если изменяется дата встречи, происходил Event, который вышлет уведомления об изменении всем участникам.

Либо, если есть идеи, как это можно лучше реализовать, буду очень благодарен. Проверка изменений в контроллере в рассмотрение не входит. Нужен именно какой то триггер, который наблюдал бы изменение в самой сущности непосредственно.

```
class Meeting{
    /**
      * @var DateTime
      * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
    */
    private $date;

    /**
      * @param DateTime $date
      * @return Meeting
    */
   public function setDate($date)
   {
      if($this->date !== $date){
        // todo: send messages
      }

      $this->date = $date;

      return $this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильным решением будет использование [Doctrine Entity Listeners](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners)

В объекте класса PreUpdateEventArgs показываются все изменения в сущности и можно делать все что угодно.